# Display content based on sign in state via OAuth

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0

I have my api behind a third party OAuth (ex. google, twitter, etc). When a user hits `/api/login`, they are redirected into the OAuth flow and then sent back to my callback `/api/login/callback`. I store their login info and then send back a same-site http only session cookie to validate their user id. On subsequent requests, I retrieve that session cookie to get their user info and then perform requests using the OAuth token stored earlier.

Now, I want to create a frontend to go with my backend REST api. When a user goes to my `/` route they get a generic about page along with a sign in button. The sign in button redirects to my `/api/login` route and eventually back to my `/api/login/callback`. Now, the callback will redirect again to the `/` route. Subsequent requests made will have the session cookie attached and will go through.

My problem arises in that I don't know how to communicate to my frontend that my user is logged in. Because my session cookie is http only I can't access the cookie on page load to render a different UI for logged in users.

Some ideas I've had:

- Hit up a `/api/me` URL that returns 401 or 200 depending on if the session cookie was sent. The problem with this is that this will leave the frontend in a limbo while the request is resolving.
- Make the cookie not https only. However, I've read online that this makes it vulnerable to XSS attacks.
- Send a second, non https only cookie as well to show that the session cookie exists. If this cookie is tampered with the worst that can happen is that a user will receive a 401 error later down the road when they make an API call without the session cookie.
- Put something in local storage or in a cookie before the request to signify a user hit log in and check for it on page load. However, I won't know if the login succeeded or not.
- Create a second page specifically for unsigned in users on the `/` route. Then, the callback can redirect to `/signed-in`. However, how will my `/signed-in` route know if a user navigated there or if the server redirected them? (ex. if the user autocomplete's the browser bar to the `/signed-in` route after their session expires)

Out of all these the third approach seems the most viable (the second cookie). However, this seems like a very trivial problem that someone has solved before. What am I missing here?

*Note: I don't want to use ssr here. If I was using ssr I could simply just check for the session cookie server-side on the `/` route and reply with a different HTML template.*

**Edit**: I could combine ideas 3 and 4. Put something in a store before sign in. If sign in fails, have my server redirect to a `/fail` page. If not, redirect to `/`. Then, `/` can reload the store on page load. `/fail` would also delete the stored item so that a user who failed can't just immediately go back to `/` and see they are logged in. The only unauthorized people who would see my user ui on `/` would be

1. Users who close out of the page during their login (never finish their login so never redirected to `/fail` to delete the store)
2. Users who revoke their OAuth token. This will have to be caught later down the road when my server receives a 401.

I could also add in a third "authorizing" state. I would set this before login. On page load with the authorizing state, I'd make a request in the background to validate that the user finished signing in. If I get a 401 from my server I'd have to move the user out of the authorized page. It wouldn't be nice but it'd occur less often than if I didn't use the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Before hitting sign in set a temporary loading value inside a store (cookie, framework store, localstorage, etc).
2. If the callback URL receives a failure value, redirect to the `/fail` route. `/fail` will set a failure value inside the store and redirect to `/`.
3. If the callback URl receives a success value, redirect to the `/success` route. `/success` will replace the temporary value with a success value.
4. On page load, read the store.

   - If the store is empty its a new user.
   - If the store has a temporary value, they never get redirected after the callback. Show a toast about an error and then display the sign in page.
   - If the store has a failure value, they failed the OAuth. Again, show a toast and display the sign in page.
   - If the store has a success value, everything went right. Show the user UI.
5. Eventually, the user may want to revoke their token. If they do, my app will not know until I make a request to a protected api endpoint with their token. If so, just pass the 401 to my frontend. I can show a modal saying they are unauthorized and then replace the success store value with an empty value.